# How do I use generate_series() in SQL in the middle of a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I use generate_series() in SQL in the middle of a string?

Ex:
'This is the 1 string.'
'This is the 2 string.'
'This is the 3 string.'

I'm looking to generate numbers from 1 to 10000, so I know I would use generate_series(1, 10000), but how can I use this in the middle of a string?

I'm trying to insert this into table 'xyz' column 'strings'.

I have tried this code but it obviously gave me an error:
INSERT INTO xyz (strings) 'This is the ' || generate_series(1, 10000) || ' string.';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do generate numbers(20) and insert each one in a separate row.

```
create table t(x varchar(100))

insert into t 
select 'This is ' || cast(x.* as varchar(20)) || ' string'
  from generate_series(1,20) x
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b646bd97e9aa3a8bb131dbb0335953ca

Comment: Thank you for this information. Can you explain what these two statements do please? 'cast(x.* as varchar(20))' and the 'x' at the end.

Comment: generate series list out a set of "numeric" and as you wish to insert the values into a string field, you would need to type cast. This is being done by the cast function

Comment: You don't need the type cast - it is done implicitly: `select 'This is ' || x || ' string' from generate_series(1,20) x`

Answer (score 0):

To complement what [George Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7137090/george-joseph) and  [Simon Perepelitsa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199607/simon-perepelitsa) answered, the final SQL would look like:

```
insert into xyz(strings) 
    (select 'This is ' || x || ' string' from generate_series(1,20) x)
```

Hope This Help!